# C# MemoryCache Changing Data by Itself

Tags: c#, memorycache

Im working on MemoryCache here's several of my Code

Cache Class

```
    private static string policy = "__";
    public static void SaveTocache(string cacheKey, object savedItem,int hour = 43800)
    {
        if (!cacheKey.StartsWith(policy)) cacheKey = policy + cacheKey;
        CacheItemPolicy cacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy();
        cacheItemPolicy.AbsoluteExpiration = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddHours(hour));
        RemoveFromCache(cacheKey);
        MemoryCache.Default.Add(cacheKey, savedItem, cacheItemPolicy);
    }
    public static T GetFromCache<T>(string cacheKey) where T : class
    {
        if (!cacheKey.StartsWith(policy)) cacheKey = policy + cacheKey;
        return MemoryCache.Default[cacheKey] as T;
    }
    public static void RemoveFromCache(string cacheKey)
    {
        if(!cacheKey.StartsWith(policy))cacheKey = policy + cacheKey;
        foreach (string key in MemoryCache.Default.Where(obj=> obj.Key.StartsWith(cacheKey)).Select(obj=> obj.Key))
        {
            MemoryCache.Default.Remove(key);
        }
    }
    public static bool IsInCache(string cacheKey)
    {
        if (!cacheKey.StartsWith(policy)) cacheKey = policy + cacheKey;
        return MemoryCache.Default[cacheKey] != null;
    }
```

So I Have a class called Log when I add a New Log theres a bug, heres the code

```
        Models.Log l = new Models.Log();
        l.LogId = Guid.NewGuid();
        l.Topic = topic;
        l.PIC = pic;
        l.LogStatusId = logStatus;
        l.LogRarityId = logRarity;
        l.LogTypeId = logType;
        l.SavedUser = savedUser;
        l.RequestedUser = requestedUser;
        l.Division = division;
        l.InsertedDate = DateTime.Now;
        l.Description = description;
        List<Models.Log> list = getData();
        Utility.Connect.Agla15Context.Logs.Add(l);
        Utility.Connect.Agla15Context.SaveChanges();
        string caches = cacheName;
        list.Add(l);
        Utility.CacheHelper.SaveTocache(caches, list);
```

The bug is myprevious object(cache values) for example:
3 Object A,B,C
my next object(cache values) for example:
4 Object A,B,C,D

So I want to remove Object A,B,C by calling RemoveFromCache and adding Object(cache values) A,B,C,D

when I take take the cache by calling GetFromCache sometimes I got Object(cache values) A,B,C and sometimes I got Object(cache values) A,B,C,D what happen to my code.

Or the simplified one look like this

```
List<String> a = new List<String>(){"A","B","C"};
Utility.CacheHelper.SaveTocache("MyKey",a);
List<String> b = Utility.CacheHelper.GetFromCache<List<String>>("MyKey");//A,B,C
b.add("D");
Utility.CacheHelper.SaveTocache("MyKey",b);
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    List<String> b = Utility.CacheHelper.GetFromCache<List<String>>("MyKey");//Sometimes A,B,C sometimes A,B,C,D
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `A,B,C` and `A,B,C,D`?

Comment: All those `policy + cacheKey;` statements  add absolutely nothing to the question but do distract.

Comment: Incomplete and unconvincing. Create an [mcve] .

Comment: @mjwills  A,B,C and A,B,C,D are my objects

Comment: Are they keys or values @GradyLeif?

Comment: @mjwills its the values

Comment: Change `Utility.CacheHelper.SaveTocache(caches, list);` to `Utility.CacheHelper.SaveTocache(caches, list.ToList());` Does that fix it?

Comment: @mjwills not yet..

Comment: What does `not yet` mean? It still doesn't work?

Comment: @mjwills yeah It still doesn't work I think the problem is the memory address the cache sometimes take the last memory address

Comment: With your last edit you come close to an mcve but two small errors give away that you didn't actually compiled or ran this. It won't show the behaviour you claim and the whole question is still meaningless.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change:

```
Utility.CacheHelper.SaveTocache("MyKey",a);
```

to:

```
Utility.CacheHelper.SaveTocache("MyKey",a.ToList());
```

and:

```
List<String> b = Utility.CacheHelper.GetFromCache<List<String>>("MyKey");
```

to:

```
List<String> b = Utility.CacheHelper.GetFromCache<List<String>>("MyKey").ToList();
```

*Technically just the latter change is required - the former will make it even more bulletproof.*

This is necessary since if any entries adding to the MemoryCache will be [shared amongst callers](https://roberthope.com/2013/02/09/be-careful-interacting-with-any-objects-retrieved-from-cache/) - so if one caller manipulates the `List` then other callers will also see that manipulated list.

By calling `ToList` you ensure that each caller gets its own copy of the `List` - so items added to one won't be seen in the other.